# Using Xilinx ISE tools, "does not have a port named" error

Tags: verilog, xilinx, ise

I'm a verilog Beginner.

I created a design using straight-up Verilog then tested it using the ISE design tools.  Works great.

I would like to synthesize this to see the resources that will be consumed but to do so seems to require a schematic file.  So I created a symbol for the Verilog cicruit and then created a new schematic, plopping my symbol onto the schematic and attaching some I/O markers.

When I tried to compile the schematic (AKA 'Implement the Design'), I got errors on every I/O. Here's an example:

> ERROR:HDLCompilers:91 - "mm.vf" line 35 Module 'method2_MUSER_mm' does
>   not have a port named 'LL1'

The other errors are identical except the line number and port name changes.

My Verilog symbol is indeed called 'method2'.  The schematic has a I/O definition for LL1.  mm.vf is a file being generated by ISE.

I have no idea what it is looking for or how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your module symbol probably doesn't have the same name as the underlying Verilog.
Make sure there is a port named LL1 in your Verilog module.

Comment: I believe you're correct. I created a new project and retraced my steps.  There was a 'define ports' window that I vaguely recall from before.  I made sure the ports were named appropriately and the error didn't occur again.